# Python TCP Sockets - Single Client to Multiple Servers

Tags: python

I have about 200 ip controlled power-bars that I need to connect to and control over TCP sockets. So far I can connect to a single power-bar and control it without issue. Where my issue lies is in how to connect to, play ping pong, as well as send and receive commands for all 200 in one client.

I have researched, hopefully exhaustively, and at most all I can find is a pointer towards [select](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html), or [twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) - but only for multiple clients connecting to a single server (whereas I need the reverse). All I really need is a prod in the right direction. I can create the sockets for all 200, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to connect to each device using the IP and Port (60000) and send and receive the proper messages in a non-blocking manner.

Any pointers in the general direction would be greatly appreciated. Hopefully this answer will help someone else with a similar issue to solve. Thanks.

Comment: It's no different from having 200 clients connecting to 200 servers. You could start multiple processes, and keep your client process simple. The part where you're wrong is that you never had 1 client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're learning about non-blocking patterns in Python at the right time ;) There's a plethora of ways to do it so I'm not really surprised you're confused. You've named `twisted`, which is the most mature framework, and there's also `asyncio`, which is built into Python 3+. Pick which ever one is easiest for you to learn. As you can see, they're very similar in style.

asyncio_client.py

```
import asyncio
from uuid import uuid4

class Echo(asyncio.Protocol):
    def __init__(self):
        self.identity = uuid4().hex

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        message = '{}: hello world'.format(self.identity)
        transport.write(message.encode())

    def data_received(self, data):
        print(data.decode())

def echo_factory():
    return Echo()

async def connect_to_server(loop):
    await loop.create_connection(echo_factory, host='127.0.0.1', port=6000)

def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(connect_to_server(loop))
    loop.create_task(connect_to_server(loop))
    loop.create_task(connect_to_server(loop))
    loop.run_forever()

main()
```

twisted_client.py

```
from uuid import uuid4
from twisted.internet import endpoints, protocol, reactor

class Echo(protocol.Protocol):
    def __init__(self):
        self.identity = uuid4().hex

    def connectionMade(self):
        message = '{}: hello world'.format(self.identity)
        self.transport.write(message.encode())

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print(data.decode())

def connect_to_server(factory):
    return endpoints.clientFromString(reactor, 'tcp:6000:host=127.0.0.1').connect(factory)

def main():
    factory = protocol.ClientFactory.forProtocol(Echo)
    connect_to_server(factory)
    connect_to_server(factory)
    connect_to_server(factory)
    reactor.run()

main()
```